# Where is 'a1' bound in sortf from the book Let over Lambda?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sorting-network, let-over-lambda

The book "Let over Lambda" by Doug Hoyte describes a fast sorting function for fixed sized inputs via [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network):

```
(defmacro! sortf (comperator &rest places)
  (if places
    `(tagbody
      ,@(mapcar
        #`(let ((,g!a #1=,(nth (car a1) places))
                (,g!b #2=,(nth (cadr a1) places)))
            (if (,comperator ,g!b ,g!a)
              (setf #1# ,g!b
                    #2# ,g!a)))
        (build-batcher-sn (length places))))))
```

Where does the symbol 'a1' in the expressions '(car a1)' and '(cadr a1)' come from?

Btw. 'defmacro!' is a macro to define macros that introduces 'g!{symbol}' syntax to create a fresh symbol via 'gensym'.  And 'build-batcher-sn' builds a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) using [Batcher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort).

Comment: Thanks @Sylwester, my tablet keyboard doesn't have backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this strange as well as `mapcar` will only take a function and a `let` does not qualify. Thus there has to be something else and surpris surprise `` #` `` is a reader-macro that creates a function around the expression that follows:

```
'#`(list a b c) 
; ==> (lambda (a1) `(list a b c))
```

Notice I quote it and since it's a read-macro it still expands but the result gets quoted.  So `a1` comes from the reader-macro. Here is it's definition and activation:

```
(defun |#`-reader| (stream sub-char numarg)
  (declare (ignore sub-char))
  (unless numarg (setq numarg 1))
  `(lambda ,(loop for i from 1 to numarg
                  collect (symb 'a i))
     ,(funcall
        (get-macro-character #\`) stream nil)))

(set-dispatch-macro-character
  #\# #\` #'|#`-reader|)
```

And the code in question:

```
'#`(let ((,g!a #1=,(nth (car a1) places))
                (,g!b #2=,(nth (cadr a1) places)))
            (if (,comperator ,g!b ,g!a)
              (setf #1# ,g!b
                    #2# ,g!a)))
; ==>
(lambda (a1)
 `(let ((,g!a ,(nth (car a1) places)) 
        (,g!b ,(nth (cadr a1) places)))
   (if (,comperator ,g!b ,g!a) 
       (setf ,(nth (car a1) places) ,g!b ,(nth (cadr a1) places) ,g!a))))
```

To make use of more arguments you add the number in front:

```
'#2`(list ,a1 ,a2)
; ==> (lambda (a1 a2) `(list ,a1 ,a2))
```